# MySQL: How to remove value matching another column from beginning or end of column?

Tags: mysql

I'm parsing through TV program data stored in an Sql table, and that data has two columns, one for the program title as a whole (e.g. the series name) and then one for the program's subtitle (e.g. the individual episode title). However the program subtitle quite often contains the series name within it as well, either at the beginning of the string or at the end, or both, in the following formats:

e.g. so with a Title of "Horizon" and a correct subtitle of "The £10 Million Challenge", the following are possible combinations for the value in the Subtitle field:

- Horizon: The £10 Million Challenge
- The £10 Million Challenge: Horizon
- Horizon: The £10 Million Challenge: Horizon

instead of a colon followed by a space, the separator could also be space hyphen space like so: "Horizon - The £10 Million Challenge - Horizon"

So essentially what I want to do is for each row in the table, if the subtitle contains the value in the Title column at the beginning of the subtitle (followed by ': ' or ' - ') or if that value is at the end of the column (preceded by ': ' or ' - ') or both, then update that subtitle to remove that prefix or suffix. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to break the trimming of the prefix & suffix into two seperate queries to make it easier, along with a 3rd check as i've noticed sometimes the program title is in brackets before the subtitle. This is what I used in the end (followed by a final operation to trim any left-over whitespace from the columns).

```
UPDATE table
    set subtitle = (case
            when subtitle like concat(title,': %') /*Title: Subtitle*/
            then trim(LEADING concat(title,': ') FROM subtitle)

            when subtitle like concat(title,' - %') /*Title - Subtitle*/
            then trim(LEADING concat(title,' - ') FROM subtitle)

            when subtitle like concat('(',title,') %') /*(Title) Subtitle*/
            then trim(LEADING concat('(',title,') ') FROM subtitle)
            else subtitle end);

UPDATE table
    set subtitle = (case
            when subtitle like concat('%: ',title) /*Subtitle: Title*/
            then trim(TRAILING concat(': ',title) FROM subtitle)

            when subtitle like concat('% - ',title) /*Subtitle - Title*/
            then trim(TRAILING concat(' - ',title) FROM subtitle)

            when subtitle like concat('%(',title,') ') /*Subtitle (Title)*/
            then trim(TRAILING concat('(',title,') ') FROM subtitle)
            else subtitle end);

UPDATE table
    set subtitle = trim(BOTH ' ' FROM subtitle);
```

Thanks to @gordon-lindoff.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the title name in the subtitle field?

I think you should just extract the actual name and then do what you want with it.  I think this requires a massive case statement:

```
update table t
    set subtitle = (case when subtitle like concat(title, ':%', title)
                         then trim(substring_index(substring_index(subtitle, ':', 2), ':', -1)))
                         when subtitle like concat(title, '-%', title)
                         then trim(substring_index(substring_index(subtitle, '-', 2), '-', -1)))
                         when subtitle like concat('%:', title)
                         then trim(substring_index(subtitle, ':', 1))
                         when subtitle like concat('%-', title)
                         then trim(substring_index(subtitle, '-', 2))
                         else subtitle
                   end)
```

Test this out in a `select` first.  Also, this won't work in some cases if the subtitle has hyphens or colons in its name.

Comment: I don't want the title name in the subtitle field though. Thnks for that anyway :) i'll give it a go.

Comment: @JohnBergqvist . . . These should remove the title name in the subtitle field.  It seems strange that it is there to begin with.